# Physics: Liquid Splashes too much

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I have a problem with physics. I am trying to make a spoon removing a fluid in a cauldron. The problem is when I introduce the spoon into the liquid the liquid splashes a lot.

[image]

[image]

I tried changing a lot of parameters, even viscosity from Water to Honey but it changed not enough. Resolution is 150 for Domain.

Maybe is because of keyframes? The spoon moves too fast?

I attach the blend file if it helps you.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I know this has already been answered, but how do you get the fluid to simulate? I've tested your file and can't get the fluid in the cauldron to actually move/churn. Asking because I actually want that splashy effect you're getting for another project.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

When the spoon is selected as Fluid/Control there are two parameters which must be changed:

Attraction strength: with positive value attracts the fluid and with negative repels it.

Velocity strenght: the influence of the  spoon's velocity with the fluid.

Just try configurations until get what you like.

Answer (score 2):

In the "Liquid" menu in the domain settings, try lowering the FLIP Ratio value.

The fluid simulator actually uses two methods to generate fluid data, FLIP, and PIC. FLIP results in a splashy, unstable liquid while PIC will give a more smooth and less splash-prone liquid.